# Prove $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+t^{4+\sqrt{15}})}{1+t}\mathrm dt= -\frac{\pi^2}{12}(\sqrt{15}-2)+\ln (2) \ln(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})+\ln(\phi) \ln(2+\sqrt{3})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Prove that:

> \begin{equation}
> \int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(1+t^{4+\sqrt{15}}\right)}{1+t}\mathrm dt= -\frac{\pi^2}{12}(\sqrt{15}-2)+\ln (2) \ln(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})+\ln(\phi) \ln(2+\sqrt{3})
> \end{equation}

where $\phi$ is the golden ratio.

---

My friend gave me this challenging problem but I cannot prove it into the given expression. She doesn't know either how to approach this problem. I have tried to use a substitution to obtain the improper integral so that I can use the derivative of beta function but it failed. I also tried to use Taylor series for $\frac{1}{1+t}$ and $\ln\left(1+t^{4+\sqrt{15}}\right)$ but I am unable to derive the result from double sums of series. Could anyone here please help me how to prove it? Any method is welcome and also any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with contour integration? If so, give it a try.

Comment: @Assaultous2 No, I am not. But if you familiar with contour integration, you may give a try

Comment: This is old problem, you can find it on there

Comment: @chinamath 'there' where?

Comment: A similar integral has been evaluated here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426325/evaluate-int-01-frac-log-left-1x2-sqrt3-right1xdx/428709#428709

Comment: Mr. @Superabound Thank you for the link ヾ(@^▽^@)ノ

Comment: You might be interested in looking at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/571116/19661).

Comment: Thank you Mr. @VladimirReshetnikov (^◡^)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See second integral in theorem 7 [here](http://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/243.pdf).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I don't have time for retyping a 30-pages paper here.

Comment: Maybe just put a commentary?

Comment: No, because this answers OP's question

Comment: This is a valid answer. In case the original link invalidates, [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20140822171427/http://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/243.pdf) is the archived version.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov thank you

Comment: I wonder if stackexchange could have a repository of files in order to avoid this kind of problems