# A curious equation containing an integral $\int_0^{\pi/4}\arctan\left(\tan^x\theta\right)d\theta=\frac{\ln2\cdot\ln x}{16}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, transcendental-equations

I came across an interesting problem that I do not know how to solve:

> Find $x>0$ such that
>   $$\int_0^{\pi/4}\arctan\left(\tan^x\theta\right)d\theta=\frac{\ln2\cdot\ln x}{16}.$$

Could you suggest how to approach it?

Comment: It is easy to show such an $x$ exists using the intermediate value theorem, but it seems implausible that this $x$ can be found in closed form, given how horrible the answer to the integral is even for $x=2$...

Comment: $\arctan z = \frac{1}{2} i (\log(1-i z)-\log(1+i z))$ might be useful

Comment: @Chappers Why is it horrible? ${\large\int}_0^{\pi/4}\arctan\left(\tan^2\theta\right)d\theta=\frac{\pi^2}{16}+\chi_2\!\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)$.

Comment: See [Herglotz integral](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522913).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only positive answer is $$x=3+\sqrt{8}.$$
The corresponding integral (in a slightly different form) is given as formula (17) and its proof is given by Theorem 10 in the paper *"A restricted Epstein zeta function and the evaluation of some definite integrals"*[$^{[1]}$](http://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/243.pdf)[$^{[2]}$](http://web.archive.org/web/20140822171427/http://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/243.pdf), H. Muzaffar, K. S. Williams, Acta Arith. 104 (2002), 23-66, DOI:10.4064/aa104-1-2.

The same integral also appears as formula 120 in section 4.1.6, page 169, in the book *"Handbook of Special Functions: Derivatives, Integrals, Series and Other Formulas"*[$^{[3]}$](https://goo.gl/3C6uho)[$^{[4]}$](https://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781584889564), Yuri A. Brychkov, Chapman and Hall/CRC, ISBN 978-1584889564.

Answer (score 5):

It would be amazing if this had a closed form solution. My approach was to use Newton's method, with a simple trapezoidal rule for the integral. For all initial guesses I tried I obtained the numerical result $x \approx 5.8284271247461$. Lookup using W|A or the ISC reveals that the most likely candidate is the algebraic number
$$
x = 3  +  2\sqrt{2} \approx \color{red}{5.8284271247461}90.
$$
If we can prove that there is a unique solution then it will suffice to prove that 
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\arctan\left(\tan^{3+2\sqrt{2}}\theta\right)d\theta=\frac{\ln2\cdot\ln (3+2\sqrt{2})}{16}.$$

Comment: It matches with at least 700 decimal digits of precision.

Comment: See [Herglotz integral](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522913).

Comment: What is the ISC?

Comment: @Farnight Inverse Symbolic Calculator: http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/

Answer (score 4):

This question is obviously related to the topic of **Herglotz integrals**. The following six links will provide you with a wealth of relevant information:

- [Evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{\log \left( 1+x^{2+\sqrt{3}}\right)}{1+x}\mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426325)
- [How to find $\int_0^\infty\frac{\log\left(\frac{1+x^{4+\sqrt{15}}}{1+x^{2+\sqrt{3}}}\right)}{\left(1+x^2\right)\log x}\mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701346)
- [Are there other cases similar to Herglotz's integral $\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1+t^{4+\sqrt{15}}\right)}{1+t}\ \mathrm dt$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522913)
- [Integral $\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{\left(1+x\right)\left(1+x^{-\left(2+\sqrt3\right)}\right)}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563204)
- [Prove $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+t^{4+\sqrt{15}})}{1+t}\mathrm dt= -\frac{\pi^2}{12}(\sqrt{15}-2)+\ln (2) \ln(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})+\ln(\phi) \ln(2+\sqrt{3})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904152)
- [Integrate $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x^a)}{1+x}\, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195297)

Comment: Why is this obvious? The fact that arctan can be written in terms of logs and the irrational exponent suggests there is a connection but I wouldn't say it's obvious?

Comment: @Lucian The second link has nothing to do with Herglotz integrals.