# Hard Logarithm Integral

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms

I recently had this integral in my homework and don't really know how to proceed.
  $\int^1_0\frac{\ln (1+x^{2+ \sqrt3})}{x+1}dx$

So far I figured that $ \int^1_0\frac{\ln (1+x^{a})}{x+1}dx= \int^1_0\frac{\ln (1+x^{-a})}{x+1}dx+a\frac{\pi^2}{12}$,

but this doesn't seem too useful.

Comment: Homework in what course, if I may ask?

Comment: This was for my physics course.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426325/evaluate-int-01-frac-log-left-1x2-sqrt3-right1x-mathrm-dx